# I want to integrate Crystal reports or SSRS reports in react js

Tags: reactjs, iframe, reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008

I want to integrate reports in React JS (Using technology like Crystal reports or SSRS).

How to load reports in the React web application?

I tried to load SSRS by placing reportUrl in iframe in react js but it's showing an unauthorized error.
I want to make that on click of a button react load report.